# http enconding of querystring value

Tags: http, encoding

I have to encode querystring value in a http request in Java. For example:

http://mysite.com/service?name=James Smith&address=my street

must become:

http://mysite.com/service?name=James%20Smith&address=my%20street

I have to do this in a method where I have querystring value in input, so I have to encode only the value (James Smith, my street, ecc.). I was thinking about using this method org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil.encodeWithinQuery: is this right? I have seen many confusing discussion about encoding http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can URLEncode the URL with

```
yourNewURL = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(oldurl.toString(), "ISO-8859-1").replace("+", "%20"));
```

Look at this discussion for further explanations:

[URLEncoder not able to translate space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character)

Comment: This method replace spaces with "+", but not with "%20"

Comment: However, I'm not sure if I have to encode using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or RFC-3986 in my case. If i look at http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp and try the "Try It Yourself" section, spaces are replaced by "+".