# java.net.URLEncoder.encode encodes space as + but I need %20

Tags: java, android, urlencode, url-encoding

As the title says: which encoder would give me space as `%20` as opposed to `+`? I need it for android. java.net.URLEncoder.encode gives `+`

Answer (score 26):

Android has it's own `Uri` class which you could use.

E.g.

```
String url = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com").buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("q", "foo bar")
    .appendQueryParameter("xml", "<Hellö>")
    .build().toString();
```

results in

`http://www.google.com?q=foo%20bar&xml=%3CHell%C3%B6%3E`

> [`Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29) Encodes characters in the given string as '%'-escaped octets using the UTF-8 scheme. Leaves letters ("A-Z", "a-z"), numbers ("0-9"), and unreserved characters ("_-!.~'()*") intact.

Note: only `_-.*` are considered unreserved characters by `URLEncoder`. `!~'()` would get converted to `%21%7E%27%28%29`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace the  `+` by yourself.

Example:

```
System.out.println(java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Hello World", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));
```

For more look at this post:

[URLEncoder not able to translate space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character)