# urllib.unquote_plus(s) does not convert plus symbol to space

Tags: python

from the documents, the urllib.unquote_plus should replce plus signs by spaces.
but when I tried the below code in IDLE for python 2.7, it did not.

```
>>s = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/?q1=xx%2Bxx%2Bxx'
>>urllib.unquote_plus(s)
>>'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/?q1=xx+xx+xx'
```

I also tried doing something like `urllib.unquote_plus(s).decode('utf-8').` 
is there a proper to decode the url component?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`%2B` is the escape code for a *literal* `+`; it is being unescaped entirely correctly.

Don't confuse this with the *URL escaped* `+`, which is the escape character for spaces:

```
>>> s = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/?q1=xx+xx+xx'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote_plus(s)
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/?q1=xx xx xx'
```

`unquote_plus()` only decodes encoded spaces to literal spaces (`'+'` -> `' '`), not encoded `+` symbols (`'%2B'` -> `'+'`).

If you have input to decode that uses `%2B` instead of `+` where you expected spaces, then those input values were perhaps *doubly* quoted, you'd need to unquote them twice. You'd see `%` escapes encoded too:

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus('Hello world!')
'Hello+world%21'
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus(urllib.quote_plus('Hello world!'))
'Hello%2Bworld%2521'
```

where `%25` is the quoted `%` character.

Comment: Your comment contradicts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character. Not sure who's right or wrong, but seems like this is something that would easily confuse somebody building an API using Python and using Android to develop for it

Comment: How do that question and this answer contradict at all?

Comment: Spaces are encoded to `+`, but a `+` in the original data is encoded to `%2B`. There is no contradiction here; you are confusing original unencoded data with the encoded result.

Comment: @Nallath: thanks for the edit, but then also update the *question*. This answer was written to cover Python 2, not Python 3, because that's what the question asker used at the time.

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't spaces, those are actual pluses. A space is %20, which in that part of the URL is indeed equivalent to +, but %2B means a literal plus.