# REST API, can't put "%20" or "+" in my URL for spaces. The URL isn't being fetched

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jira-rest-api

I receive an error saying **org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null** from the console meaning that my URL sent a bad request that the server could not understand.

However, whenever i put a URL with no **%20** or **+** signs for the spaces

Example: 
**http://ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com:8061/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=SUP&maxResults=2** it works and my data is displayed on my local page.

```
String username = "confidential";
String password = "confidential";

private static final String jiraBaseURL = "http://ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com:8061/rest/api/search?jql=project%3D%22Customer%20Support%22%20%26%20type%20%3D%20%22Change%20Request%22%20&maxResults=2";
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;





private HttpHeaders createHeadersWithAuthentication() {
    String plainCreds = username + ":" + password;
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCreds.getBytes());
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

    return headers;
}




@RequestMapping("/cr-follow-up")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getData()
{
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    httpHeaders = createHeadersWithAuthentication();
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(jiraBaseURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use some uri builder like spring UriComponentsBuilder ?

Comment: What happens if you put in a space instead.

Comment: When you meant by adding did you do a uriencode ?

Comment: I haven't tried using a UriComponentsBuilder, hmm I will try it

Comment: If i use a space it doesnt work

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: I edited my code and if anyone has ideas please help with how im displaying it thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your URL with `URLEncoder.encode()`

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: Then try using the object URL. It should format it as required.

Comment: I will edit my code post and show u how im returning my string, and see if u have any ideas to fix my problem :/

Comment: and the problem is 100% in my URL

Comment: Is that answer helping? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885521/spring-resttemplate-url-encoding

Comment: the issue i found is that the %20 ( space ) or %3D ( equal sign ) are being encoded already in my URL but when I provide that as my string it doesnt read it, and produces an error of 400