# URI removes / from path

Tags: java, rest, url, resttemplate

Good morning everyone. I have the following code:

```
String url = "https://example/example/rest/verify/";
<!-- It is absolutely necessary that code starts with / -->
String code = "/gRmaik5E5rUAoJFy7iovg==";

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).path(code);
UriComponents components = builder.build(true);
URI uri = components.toUri();
       
ResponseEntity<String> response  = new RestTemplate(requestFactory1).exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

The problem is that the uri variable is assigned to the RestTemplate constructor as `https://example/example/rest/verify/gRmaik5E5rUAoJFy7iovg==`, that is, it removes the initial `/` from the code variable.

I would need the url to look like this: `https://example/example/rest/verify//gRmaik5E5rUAoJFy7iovg==` with two `//` in the variable code.

Any requests?

Comment: I suppose you can't fix the server that is not handling urls properly, right?

Comment: Exactly, I have no option to modify it.

Comment: Have you tried to send the second forward slash as `%2F` instead of `/` and see if the server accepts it?

Comment: the solution to this might be worth a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885521/spring-resttemplate-url-encoding

Comment: Great! The way you say @MatteoNNZ if it works correctly.

Comment: Does the URI itself have only one `/`, or is RestTemplate changing `//` to `/`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) to build the URI.
This builds the URI the way you want it:

```java
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
URI uri = uriBuilder.setPath(uriBuilder.getPath() + code).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'fromUri' method to create instance of UriComponentsBuilder.

`UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(new URI(url))`

Once you set URI instead of path, you will not get any issues for / .