# MalformedURLException although I have already replaced spaces with %20

Tags: java, url

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins="+origin+"&destinations="+destination+"&mode=driving&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial";
url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Output :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=150%20Sutter%20St%20San%20Francisco,%20CA,%20United%20States&destinations=1%20Palmer%20Sq%20E
Princeton,%20NJ%2008542&mode=driving&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial
```

But I am getting an error saying :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character in URL
```

Can some one help me out ..

Comment: I used the marked answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character). I hope it works for you.

Comment: Just paste the resulting URL into any URL validator? IMHO you should have done this before asking on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 17):

*(Note: see update below)*

Use the [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class from the `java.net` package. Spaces are not the only characters that need to be escaped in URLs, and the `URLEncoder` will make sure that all characters that need to be encoded are properly encoded.

Here's a small example:

```
String url = "http://...";
String encodedUrl = null;

try {
    encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
    // Can be safely ignored because UTF-8 is always supported
}
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments and other answers to this question, the `URLEncoder` class is only safe to encode the query string parameters of a URL. I currently rely on Guava's [`UrlEscapers`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html) to safely encode different parts of a URL.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. UrlEncoder encodes spaces as "+", which is acceptable for the query part of a URL, but not for the path part. See https://web.archive.org/web/20151218094722/http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding#Thereservedcharactersaredifferentforeachpart

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't call `String.replaceAll` to encode an URL, instead you should use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)`.

Note that you only need to encode the query string parameters (name and value) and not the entire URL.

When encoding a String using `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)`, the following rules apply:

- The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0"
  through "9" remain the same.
- The special characters ".", "-", "*", and "_" remain the same.
- The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".
- All other characters are unsafe and are first    converted into one
  or more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then    each byte is
  represented by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is    the
  two-digit hexadecimal representation of the byte. The recommended encoding scheme to use is UTF-8. However, for compatibility reasons, 
  if an encoding is not specified, then the default encoding of the
  platform is used.

See [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Ex:

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" + URLEncoder.encode(origin, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem, I tried using URLEncoder and my url looked like this :    http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.googleapis.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fdistancematrix%2Fxml%3Forigins%3D150+Sutter+St+San+Francisco%2C+CA%2C+United+States%26destinations%3D410+Eddy+St%0AIthaca%2C+NY+14850%26mode%3Ddriving%26sensor%3Dfalse%26language%3Den-EN%26units%3Dimperial

Comment: @user3742241 you only need to encode the query string parameters (name and value) and not the entire URL.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer which helped me: [HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)

Its just using `URL` & `URI` objects.

Original aproach mentioned above in this thread with `URLEncoder`, encoded all characters in url including `http://` and using such `url` was throwing `exception` in `httpConnection` - therefore its not a good option. I am now using `URL/URI` approach mentioned in link, and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

`java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Hello World", "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20"));`have a nice day =).

Comment: What if they had a legitimate `+`?

Comment: Hi, have you got an example?

Comment: might as well replace space with %20 right. also when I do this I get `Hello%2520World`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
str.replaceAll("\\s","%20");
```

That should fix it