# Groovy: convert JSON array to URLencoded string?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, smartthings

I am writing an app for SmartThings (www.smartthings.com) in their own IDE. I have an input field here that is supposed to be text input. I ask for a departure address:

```
section("Departing From:"){
    input "departFrom", "text", title: "Address?"
}
```

when putting in the value of `Monterey, CA` the value magically gets changed to a JSON Array with the values of `[Monterey, CA]`

I want to pass this value to an `httpGET` statement but I need to `URLencode` it first to omit spaces, etc.I have tried `URLencoder` with no success due to the JSON array.

I have tried `join(",")` with no luck as it adds double quotes to the value.

How can I get a clean `Monterey%2C%20CA` URL encoded value from this variable?

** bear in mind someone could input any combination of numbers, spaces, and commas into this input as an address. The mapquest API I am sending it to can handle all these things as long as they dont have special characters and spaces are URL encoded.

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: yes. it fails because its an array and is expecting a string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
def l = ['Monterey', 'CA']
assert URLEncoder.encode(l.join(', ')).replaceAll('\\+','%20') == 'Monterey%2C%20CA'
```

When it comes to replacing `+` sign, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character)

Answer (score -1):

There are different types of URL encoding, but in this case there are two: One that converts spaces to %20 and one that converts spaces to +.

For the first, you'd use UriUtils:

```
def yourEncodedString = UriUtils.encodeUri(yourString.toString(), "UTF-8")
```

For the second, you'd use UrlEncoder:

```
def yourEncodedString = URLEncoder.encode(yourString.toString(), "UTF-8")
```

Alternatively (I think) you can use URLEncoder with UTF-16 to get what you want.

I've never had a fun time with UriUtils, so hopefully UrlEncoder will work for you.

Comment: as mentioned in above comments, URLencoder doesnt work because the input is an array not a string. The `tostring()` did nothing to improve. Result is `%5B%22felton%22%2C%22+ca%22%5D`. `uriutils` failed in complier `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method encodeUri() on null object`

Comment: First, make sure you have your tests coded correctly:
`def town = "felton, ca"
def encodedTown = URLEncoder.encode(town, "UTF-8")
println encodedTown
felton%2C+ca`

You should make sure that you understand **why** you need %20 instead of +. From the javadocs:
This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format.

And from the HTML specification:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:
Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by '+'

Comment: If you're still convinced you need the %20, you can do this: `println URLEncoder.encode("felton, ca", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20")`
`

Comment: Perhaps I have been unclear but as stated in my OP and comment below it, my problem is dealing with the array, not with whether its `%20` or `+`. I get `%5B%22felton%22%2C%22+ca%22%5D` which is encoding the brackets and quotes.