# How to percent encode in Java?

Tags: java, percent-encoding

How do I do percent encoding of a string, as described in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)? I.e. I do not want (IMO, weird) www-url-form-encoded, as [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595894/1212596) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20?lq=1).

If it matters, I am encoding data that is not necessarily an entire URL.

Comment: This do it for you?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html. Woops, didnt read properly. Ignore

Comment: @ZackNewsham, no, as that uses www-url-form-encoded.

Comment: Could you define "standard"? Does it have to encode spaces in the URL as `%20`, and spaces in the query string as `+`? What about other special characters?

Comment: ok, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character

Comment: Does Guava's [`PercentEscaper`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/PercentEscaper.html) work for you? Or, rather, one of [the URL escapers](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html)?

Comment: @Slanec and Zack yes, those work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Answer (score 7):

As you have identified, the standard libraries don't cope very well with the problem.

Try to use either Guava's [`PercentEscaper`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/PercentEscaper.html), or directly one of [the URL escapers](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html) depending on which part of the URL you're trying to encode.

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: Guava's com.google.common.net.PercentEscaper is marked "Beta" and therefore unstable

Comment: (Links fixed, and PercentEscaper is no longer beta since Guava 31.1. Even if you have to use an older Guava, only refrain from using @Beta APIs if you're creating a library. In an application they're fine.)

Answer (score 7):

**Guava**'s com.google.common.net.PercentEscaper (marked "Beta" and therefore unstable):

```
UnicodeEscaper basicEscaper = new PercentEscaper("-", false);
String s = basicEscaper.escape(s);
```

Workaround with **java.net.URLEncoder**:

```
try {
  String s = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  ..
}
```

Comment: I really like the workaround using java.net.URLEncoder. Dunno if "replace" (a second iteration of the string) will cause any significant performance issues during high load, but not having to include yet another dependency is a win.