# How i can get encoded(which libriary can do this) "a &" to "a%20%26" without using String.replace() function?

Tags: java, url-encoding

How I can get encoded(which `java library` can do this)

`a &` to `a%20%26`

without using `String.replace()` function?

URL Encoder -> a+%26

URIUtil.encodePath -> a%20&

UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper().escape -> a%20&

Comment: URL Encoder encodes spaces to +, I need spaces to %20

Comment: Adding that you've already tried the built-in library and that it doesn't do what you want to your question would be helpful. (I suppose it does that for form encoding)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URLEncoder not able to translate space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character)

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.catalina.util.URLEncoder is the answer