# Encode Edittext string

Tags: android

Creating app in which my requirement is to pass encode data of string.I have Edittext and i have to encode editext text.I am doing this.

```
String getstr="#"+((Editext)findviewbyid(id)).getText.tostring;

String s = URLDecoder.encode(getstr, "UTF-8");
```

Suppose Editext text is "my data "
But i am not getting proper response.
I am getting

```
%23my%2bdata%2b
```

If there is space it should be `%20` but why i am getting this.
String should be

```
%23my%20data%20.
```

Does any one has idea.What i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

URLEncoder encodes HTML form data, not URL parameter data. Check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character).