# How to encode an XML string with spaces mapped to "%20" rather than '+'?

Tags: java, xml, encoding

I have the following valid XML document:

```xml
<bundle><elem type="A"></elem></bundle>
```

I want to encode this XML string so as to send it to a third-party web service. This service requires XML to be sent encoded as a query parameter. I am trying to encode my XML using URLEncoder as follows:

```java
rawXml = "<bundle><elem type=\"A\"></elem></bundle>";
encodedXML = URLEncoder.encode(rawXML, "UTF-8");
```

This generates the following encoded string:

```
%3Cbundle%3E%3Celem+type%3D%22A%22%3E%3C%2Felem%3E%3C%2Fbundle%3E
```

When I decode this, for example using [this decoder](https://onlinexmltools.com/url-decode-xml), I get the following decoded XML document:

```xml
<bundle><elem+type="A"></elem></bundle>
```

Which is indeed a valid document. However, when I send it to the third-party web service as a query parameter, the service rejects it, even when I set the Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which is the format used by URLEncoder.

The problem lies in the plus sign. If I manually change this plus sign to "%20", the service accepts my request.

**My question is, is there a way to encode an XML string so that spaces get mapped to "%20" instead of '+'?**

Comment: If you encoded with URLEncoder, wouldn’t it make sense to decode using [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the following link would be helpful 
[URLEncoder not able to translate space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character)

One question , why do you need URL based encoding feature to encode your xml ?

Comment: Why do I need URL based encoding? I don't know that I need to, but I am not aware of an alternative. Am I supposed to use an XML encoding library?

Comment: @edoreld the URL encoder is basically to construct URLs with certain symbols in its original form will not be supported. if you are passing the xml as a request parameter then this would suit you.