# URL change encoding + instead of %20

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.
In spring MVC it replaces with %20. My controller as:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/post/{id}/{title}")
public String postView(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @PathVariable("title") String title, Model model){


    Post post = postService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("post", post);
    return "singlePost";
}
```

I need to replace the %20 with (+) or (-)
Thanks

Comment: `+` becomes `%2B`. not `%20`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decode` method of [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class. As an example, if title have url encoded values,

```
String urlDecodedTitle = URLDecoder.decode(title, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

In the path of a URL the spaces are replaced by `%20` ([RFC3986][1]), while URL query parameters follow the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` that replaces spaces by `+`.

If you need to encode a query string parameter, you can use `java.net.URLEncoder`.

But as you are using `@PathVariable`, your parameters are part of the path, hence they must be encoded with spaces replaced by `%20`. Spring provides `UriUtils.encodePath` for this task.

For example, to build a query to your `/post/{id}/{title}` mapping:

```
Long id = 1L; 
String title = "My title";
String path = "/post/" + id + "/" + UriUtils.encodePathSegment(title, "UTF-8");
```

On your `postView` method you don't need to do any decoding, as Spring does it already.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: Hi, @areus thanks for answering my Q. Im looking for an example to do the above can you help with an example, please? thanks

Comment: Was this the kind of example you were looking for?

Comment: Hmmm not really, cause the URL is already in the @GetMapping(path = "/post/{id}/{title}") so how I edit it/Decode it from the same method? sorry cause I have not done this before need to understand it more. If I'm sending the /post/id/title from JSP to that method postView() in the controller, then in there how I decode it? Still have not worked this out! Thanks for the help

Comment: You don't need to decode it. Spring will decode it. The example will produce the path `/post/1/My%20title`. As I stated in the answer, on your `postView()` method you don'nt need to do any decoding, `@PathVariable("title") String title` will contain the value `"My title"`