# Encoding URL with Spaces in Java works incorrectly

Tags: java, httpclient, urlencode, java-11

I am trying a simple url encoding that needs to be done for the URL below:

```
https://example.org/v1/x/y/Quick Brown Fox/jumps/over/
```

I use the below code:

```
String url = https://example.org/v1/x/y/Quick Brown Fox/jumps/over/;
url = UrlEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
```

Ideally, this should provide output like -

```
https://example.org/v1/x/y/Quick%20Brown%20Fox/jumps/over/
```

which is the correct encoding. Instead it ends up replacing space with `+`

Using JDK 11 - I need %20 because I am using Apache HTTP client to send HTTP request and URI does not take `+` in the URL where spaces are present.

Comment: What is this UrlEncode class?

Comment: java.net.UrlEncode

Comment: Do you mean URLEncoder? This one? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html Can you make sure the code in the question matches the code in your project

Comment: The `UrlEncode.encode()` method works as intended, since it implements the encoding for the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format. Check this stackoverflow entry for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `URI` class:

```
        URI uri = new URI("https", "//example.org/v1/x/y/Quick Brown Fox/jumps/over/", null);
        System.out.println(uri.toASCIIString()); // Should be escaped
```

Just be aware that you need to handle an `URISyntaxException`.