# White space get converted to + in url_launcher mailto scheme | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

I had integrated a mail to scheme in flutter using a url_launcher package. the subject and body were given as query parameters.

```
 final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
                  scheme: 'mailto',
                  path: 'mail@qapp.how',
                  queryParameters: {
                      'body':
                          'this is sample text'
                    } 
                );
```

This will give the text as `this+is+sample+text` in mail.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem in MATLAB which lead me to the question  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character  . Turns out the + character is a cannonical space character representation in encoded URIs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

instead of queryParameters use query.

```
final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
                  scheme: 'mailto',
                  path: 'mail@qapp.how',
                  query:
                       'body=this is sample text',
                );
```

Comment: if you have multiple queryParameters like "body" & "subject" just concatenate them with an "&". E.g. "query: 'body=$body&subject=$subject'