# StringBuilder and URLEncoder - problem with encoding?

Tags: java, kotlin, character-encoding, urlencode, stringbuilder

I have a problem with encoding a part of and URL using `URLEncoder`.

Let's say that I have:

```
override suspend fun getData(ids: String): SomeData {
    val itemIds = ids.split(",").iterator()
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    sb.append("/v1/data?ids=")
    itemIds.forEach {
        val assetsJson = myObjectMapperWrapper.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
            DataRequest(type = "Picture", id = it)
        )
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(assetsJson, Charsets.UTF_8))
        if (itemIds.hasNext()) sb.append("&data=")
    }
    val uri = sb.toString()
```

`assetsJson` looks, for example, like this: `{"type":"Picture","id":"         12345"}` (spaces in the `id` field are intentional, as this is a `String` and needs those spaces for reasons unknown (this is a shot to an API).

Encoding this string using an online tool gives me this:

> %7B%22type%22%3A%22Picture%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2012345%22%7D

It starts with `%7B%22` and the spaces are represented by `%20`. Pasting this to the URI that is used to call the API in Insomnia is working.

Using a debugger I've found out that: is encoded as:

> %7B%22type%22%3A%22Picture%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22+++++++++12345%22%7D

So no `%20` for a space character, but `+` signs.

The last problem is what is really sent to the server:

> %257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522Picture%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522+++++++++12345%2522%257D

It's `%257B%2522` instead of `%7B&22` and `+` instead of `%20`. And this is not working even in Insomnia, and the API server returns:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.Set'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (String)"%7B%22type%22%3A%22Picture%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22 12345%22%7D"; line: 1, column: 2]

What's noticeable, the space character looks normal:   instead of `+` like it was created by `StringBuilder` or `%20` like it was created by the online tool.

The string in this stack trace is `%7B%22type%22%3A%22Picture%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22 12345%22%7D"` which is close to this: `>%7B%22type%22%3A%22Picture%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2012345%22%7D` but there is only one space instead of 9, and it is represented by a regular space   instead of `%20` or `+`.

How can I fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character