# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index

Tags: jsp, url, encoding, jersey, opera

In a link I have the `{` and `}` characters.  In chrome/ff (and ie?), when I click that link it replaces `{` with `%7B` and `}` with `%7D`.  Unfortunately, in opera it doesn't.  If I `URLEncoder.encode` the link, then `%7B` becomes `%257B` in the other browsers (so then I get a 404 @ that resource).  So when I click the link in opera I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index`.  I'm confused about:

1. Why doesn't opera encode `{` and `}`?
2. Why throw an exception?  Why not just encode the URL and continue?
3. How to solve this without breaking the links (w/extra encoding) in other browsers?

Edit: we're using [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), as it says in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index
    java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
    javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:95)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:879)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:843)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:804)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusingly (i.e. it is badly named) URLEncoder is meant for passing data as parameters, not for encoding the URL itself.

We use org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil.encodePath but it looks like this has gone now (since 1.4?)  and the suggestion is to use java.net.URI instead:
[What happened to URIUtil.encodePath from commons-httpclient-3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605757/what-happened-to-uriutil-encodepath-from-commons-httpclient-3-1)

Have a look at this too: [HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)