# httpclient's (3.1) URIUtil.encodeQuery() is gone in org.apache.httpcomponents (4.4.1), any substitute?

Tags: httpclient

In my project code, there is a requirement to encode the URL. its currently using httpclient 3.1 jar and uses its method URIUtil.encodeQuery() to do the job. but we are upgrading the jar to the newer version, org.apache.httpcomponents 4.4.1.

where I couldn't find any exact substitute for encodeQuery method. it has been discussed in the post [What happened to URIUtil.encodePath from commons-httpclient-3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605757/what-happened-to-uriutil-encodepath-from-commons-httpclient-3-1).

But still I am looking for any good substitute for encodeQuery(), can anyone has suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In our project we use the URIBuilder class.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html

The builder returns the standard java URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new project I suggest to follow [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37024069/628006) by using the Builder.

On my side, as my project is old and do not want to refactor too much, I just switched to another util class in the CXF project (as it's already a dependency I have).

I just replaced the code `URIUtil.encodeQuery(strQuery)` by `URIParserUtil.escapeChars(strQuery)`

The API documentation is [here](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/common/util/URIParserUtil.html).