# DOM Parser issues in Android?

Tags: android, dom

In my application i am using DOM parser to parse XML. The DOM parser giving 100% result by using without any space in the URL string . If anything blank space in my URL string i am getting error like **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document**
This is my url string
"`www.someurl.com/queryType=new-celeb&name=ABC&category=American Foot ball`".
In the above url string there was blank space (American Foot ball)in category attribute so i am receiving exception. without blank space its working.

this is my piece of code

```
URL url= new URL("www.someurl.com/queryType=new-celeb&name=ABC&category=American Foot ball");           
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
Element ele=doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nodeList = ele.getElementsByTagName("items");
```

Give me some idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space is not a valid character for a URL, it should be encoded.  Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object)

Sounds like it may relevant. It escapes the spaces in urls