# converting a URL

Tags: java, android, string, url

I have a method

```
String Address=search.getText().toString();

private String getAddressUrl() {
     String mapUrl="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
     String add=Address; //Address is a String input by the user  
     String baseUrl1=mapUrl+"address="+add+"&sensor=true";
return baseUrl1;
}
```

If I input the string like "170 william street New York, NY" I am getting ***illegal character at query error*** because it contains spaces.

Is there any method to insert **%20** for spaces in `Address` string

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object

Comment: on a side note - Try using beginning lower case letters for local variable names and fields like  `Address`, this will make it easier for other java programmers to read your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [Uri.encode(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String add=Uri.encode(Address);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use class [UrlEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: A little gotcha with URLEncoder: It will encode spaces as `+` instead of `%20`.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, thought this was .Net for some reason.