# httpclient httpget doesn't accept square brackets

Tags: java, apache

I'm using HttpGet to return a file, and HttpGet doesn't allow the argument to be a URL, it has to be a URL, however the problem I face is that I have* to use httpclient, and I need to be able to put special characters in the URI/URL e.g. square brackets so:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/exists/rest/db/catalog?_query=//album[contains(title,"")]
```

What can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/square-brackets-in-urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[URLEncode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the portion of the url containing the special chars before passing to HttpGet with `URLEncoder.encode(yourQueryString,"UTF-8");`