# How do I replace all "[", "]" and double quotes in Java

Tags: java

I'm am having difficulty using the replaceAll method to replace square brackets and double quotes. Any ideas?

Edit:

So far I've tried:

```
replace("\[", "some_thing") // returns illegal escape character
replace("[[", "some_thing") // returns Unclosed character class
replace("^[", "some_thing") // returns Unclosed character class
```

Comment: tried replaceAll("^[", "something"), replaceAll("\[", "..."), replace("\[", " ").

Comment: You'll want to show us a small test program that includes a test String, your code, and the results you obtained.

Comment: are you replacing both of them with the same string?

Comment: What are you trying to replace them with?

Comment: Did `URLEncoder` not work, or something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301699/httpclient-httpget-doesnt-accept-square-brackets

Comment: @FailedDev - I'm going to guess they're being replaced with `%5B` and `%5D`, respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `replaceAll`, use `replace`.  The former uses regular expressions, and `[]` are special characters within a regex.

```
String replaced = input.replace("]", ""); //etc
```

The double quote is special in Java so you need to escape it with a single backslash (`"\""`).

If you want to use a regex you need to escape those characters and put them in a character class.  A character class is surrounded by `[]` and escaping a character is done by preceding it with a backslash `\`.  However, because a backslash is *also* special in Java, it also needs to be escaped, and so to give the regex engine a backslash you have to use *two* backslashes (`\\[`).

In the end it should look like this (if you were to use regex):

```
String replaced = input.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

The replaceAll method is operating against [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  You're probably just wanting to use the "[replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)" method, which despite its name, does replace all occurrences.

Looking at your edit, you probably want:

```
someString
.replace("[", "replacement")
.replace("]", "replacement")
.replace("\"", "replacement")
```

or, use an appropriate regular expression, the approach I'd actually recommend if you're willing to learn regular expressions (see Mark Peter's answer for a working example).

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll()` takes a regex so you have to escape special characters. If you don't want all the fancy regex, use `replace()`.

```
String s = "[h\"i]";
System.out.println( s.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("\"","") );
```

With double quotes, you have to escape them like so: `"\""`

Answer (score 0):

In java:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "");
```

this will replace `[]"` with nothing.

Comment: However, it will *only* replace exactly `[]"` in that order.  It wouldn't replace individual occurrences of each of those characters.

Comment: @MarkPeters Oups.. It's getting late I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you wished to replace `"`, `[` and `]` with different characters (instead of replacing all with empty String) you could use the `replaceEachRepeatedly()` method in the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEachRepeatedly%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) class from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

For example,

```
String input = "abc\"de[fg]hi\"";
String replaced = StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly(input, 
    new String[]{"[","]","\""}, 
    new String[]{"<open_bracket>","<close_bracket>","<double_quote>"});
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Prints the following:

```
abc<double_quote>de<open_bracket>fg<close_bracket>hi<double_quote>
```