# Safely pass string to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jstl

I am trying to pass a string from my java code to javascript like so:

```
myData.data = "${data.myString}";
```

This breaks if `myString` contains a `"`

I tried storing a javascript safe string instead, just replacing `"` with `\"` but then when I use `myString` in my jsp I get an ugly output with `\"` showing instead of `"`

What is the best way to safely pass a string and not mess up the rest of my output.

Comment: not a robust solution, but can you use single quotes instead?

Comment: One possibility would be to base64-encode it?

Comment: did you try to use ' (single quote) instead of " (double quote). you maybe also need to escape this.

Comment: single quotes causes the same problem, these are user submitted comments that can legitimately contain ' and "

Comment: I know nothing about Java, but there must be some way of escaping the comments?

Comment: have you tried replacing with &quot;?

Comment: `<c:out value="${data.myString}" escapeXml="true" />` - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v5r6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rsdjspbpescapexml.htm

Comment: using $quot; works.  Thanks! are there any other characters I should be worried about?

Comment: there is a list here http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

Comment: @orangegoat is there a method that does all of those changes for me?

Comment: @Lumpy take a look at http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the double quotes with `&quot;` should work

Answer (score 1):

Encode it into the html in the JSP:

```
<input id="test_hide" type="hidden" value="${URIUtil.encodeAll("http://www.google.com?q=a b","UTF-8")}">
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
 myData.data = decodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('test_hide').getAttribute('value'));
```

[Java - Convert String to valid URI object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object)

Comment: Yeah I had that originally.  My use of URLEncoder is fuzzy :)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bad solution :

Check if your string has double quotes, if yes then use

```
myData.data = '${data.myString}';
```

if it contains single quotes use

```
myData.data = "${data.myString}";
```

This will explode if you have both single and double quotes.

A good solution :

Just use

```
&quot;
```