# How to cast a string to an URL in java?

Tags: java, url

My java code is below.I wrote url=URL(s); but it is not true.I want to make a casting operation to convert a string that is taken from the user ,to an URL.How can I do this operation?Is there any method to do this?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Download Manager");
    URL url;
    String s;
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    s=scan.nextLine();
    url=URL(s);
    Download download=new Download(url);
}
```

Comment: You don't cast it. You use it to make a new URL.

Comment: user url= new URL(s); instead

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How can I take a URL from the user?

Comment: @ntf You don't. You get a `String` and you use the `String` to construct a new `URL`.

Comment: You forgot the `new` keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Convert String to valid URI object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object)

Comment: @Brandon eclipse says create method URL(String).

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast `s`.  Why not just say `url = new URL(s);`

Comment: @arajek I just want to get a URL from the User

Comment: You should use URI, not URL.

Answer (score 45):

You can't cast String to URL, since String is not a subclass of URL. You can create new instance of URL, passing String as argument to the constructor. In Java, you **always** invoke constructor using keyword *new*:

```
URL url = new URL(string);
```

Comment: Using URL constructor is deprecated in Java 20. Best practice (for a long time) is using uri.toURL() as stated by ofskyMohsen

Answer (score 10):

Using the [URL constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String%29):

```
url = new URL(s);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the URL constructor

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Download Manager");
        URL url;
        String s;
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        s=scan.nextLine();
        url= new URL(s);
        Download download=new Download(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You should first convert your string into a `URI` , then convert the `URI` into a `URL` .

For example:

```
String str = "http://google.com";
URI uri = new URI(str);
URL url = uri.toURL();
```

Please note, there are 2 unhandled exceptions; so you should wrap the above code within 2 try/catch statements.

Comment: The only correct answer. Note however that str must be encoded!

Answer (score 4):

you need to change it to `url= new URL(s);`

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 20, the URL constructor has been [deprecated](https://inside.java/2023/02/15/quality-heads-up/) and developers who still need to use URL are now encouraged to adtop the [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/class-use/URI.html) class:

If you know the input, you can use the [`java.net.URI::create`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#create(java.lang.String)) method instead:

```java
URL url = URI.create(s).toURL();
```

This method works the same behavior as the constructor, with a twist:

> This method is provided for use in situations where it is known that the given string is a legal URI, for example for URI constants declared within a program, and so it would be considered a programming error for the string not to parse as such.