# Can I use = or + in Cookie data?

Tags: json, http, cookies, base64

I am working on setting a cookie in a browser, and I'd like to base64 encode a string of data as the value.  The call to base 643 encode is trivial

```
public static String encodeToBase64(String input) {
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(input.getBytes()));
}
```

But I'm wondering, can I include a + or an = in a cookie?  My cookie generation device looks something like this

```
String parameterData = Base64Utils.encodeToBase64(JsonUtils.objectToJson(parameters));
String expires = epochMillisToExpirationString(getExpiration());
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("data=");
stringBuilder.append(parameterData);
```

Has anyone seen this break down?  Is there any documentation on Cookie standards that discuss this sort of issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed characters in cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

Comment: Did you check the Cookie specification?

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing the data within a URI parameter you will probably want to uri-encode the data, escaping reserved special characters.

[This question/answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object) should tell you all you need to know about how.

(!) Remember to uri-decode it next time you read it before using it internally.

Answer (score 2):

It's not cookie specific, but [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) has dialects. For example,

- [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) 'base64url'
- [RFC 1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521)
- etc

To use standard Base64 in URL requires encoding of '+', '/' and '=' characters into special percent-encoded hexadecimal sequences ('+' = '%2B', '/' = '%2F' and '=' = '%3D'). Remembering to decode those sequences when you read it in again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine, I've seen SAML response values contain special characters like this before. When in doubt encode the value :)  Are you having odd results?