# Android - Unhandled java.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: java, android, ioexception, malformedurlexception

I'm getting a MalformedURLException some code in my Android Studio project. My aim is to get and display an image from a web page, and the URL seems to be fine, but it's giving me this error.

I have already put the code in a `try`,`catch`, but that is still giving me the error.
Here is the code to grab the image and display it:

```
    try
    {
        url = new URL(items.get(position).getLink());
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Url Exception" + e);
    }

    holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());;
    holder.itemHolder.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));
```

`items.get(position).getLink()` is meant to get the link that is being displayed in a `ListView`, but even something like `URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com")` doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: can you do a Log.e("urltest", items.get(position).getLink())` to see the full url you pass to `decodeStream`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just did that and the URL seems to be looking fine. I'm trying to make a news application so here is the link that one of the list items outputted: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2691912/jpmorgan-chase-attackers-hacked-other-banks-report-says.html#tk.rss_all

Answer (score 1):

your url is [formatted without the protocol at the beginning](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) try

```
url = new URL("http://"+items.get(position).getLink());
```

sometimes the url string may have special characters, in which case you need to [encode it properly please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object).
And also, the url you posted in the comment is not an image.

Comment: Sorry @ashoke, but stackoverflow is removing it when I post the link. It does have the http protocol at the start

Answer (score 0):

it is exception beacuse of url class

add antoher catch like

```
catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click alt+enter and then import try catch section... this helped me...

Comment: You need to add more details of exactly what you did, such as which exception you used, what happened that solved the problem, etc.