# TextView is not acquiring space of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get News from one site. Some articles have images. Here is my problem: some article doesn't have images so i want remove that Imageview for that row and title textview should acquire that space.
I tried to implement it in `BaseAdapter` but `setvisibility(View.Gone)` is not working i guess.

Here is my layout file:

```
<!-- Thumbnail Image -->
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

<!-- News Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"/>
```

Here is my implementation in base adapter:

```
  NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    if(m.getThumbnailUrl() == null)
    {

     thumbNail.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Not working

    }
    else {
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    }
```

And current output is: 
I want that blank space of Imageview to be used by textview.

[image: Example]

When I try with ViewHolder for smooth transition i am unable to implement this logic:

```
if (position==-1)
    {
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(news.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether URL for image is valid or not then you can use Visibility gone concept.Use something like below code:

```
if(!URLUtil.isValidUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl())){
    thumbNail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else {
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        thumbNail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and let you know

Comment: Its not happening the way i wanted. Even i lost images for articles with image.

Comment: Text is getting the space now but i am losing images.

Comment: One newspaper is giving me layout the way i want but `isValidUrl` making Image url invalid in other newspaper feed?? Do we other options that `isValidUrl`?

Comment: Do we have ulternative to `isValidUrl`. I am not getting it online. We are so close though.

Comment: How to check that Condition if we are using ViewHolder??

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    if(m.getThumbnailUrl() == null)
    {
     thumbNail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addrule(LinearLayout.RIGHT_OF,0);
         lp.setMargins(-150,0,0,0); //set your margins for your textview as your want
         title.setLayoutParams(lp);
         Your_Linear_Layout_Name.addView(title, lp);
        //or RelativeLayoutName.addView(title, lp);
        }

        .....
```

Comment: are you sure that m.getThumbnailUrl() is returing null??
if yes try to remove `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"` when it is null, and check

Comment: did you try to remove `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"` when it is returning null?

Comment: try to add `lp.addrule(lp.RIGHT_OF,0);` to the above code, and remove setMargins if needed

Comment: Okay i will try and let you know later on.

Comment: I will only if it satisfies my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The m.getThumbnailUrl() return a String, right?

Did you try this?

```
if(m.getThumbnailUrl() == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(m.getThumbnailUrl()))
```

Try to debug and check if hit this line:

```
thumbNail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have an image for article set `LayoutParameters` for that particular `TextView` programmatically.

```
if(m.getThumbnailUrl() == null)
{

 thumbNail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) title.getLayoutParams();
 layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,0);
 layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,0);
 layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
 title.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: I got your addRule logic.

Comment: Its not getting the space.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how the ListView works. You can try something like this:

```
if(m.getThumbnailUrl() == null)
    {

     thumbNail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     LayoutParams layoutParams = title.getLayoutParams();
     layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
     layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
     title.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
    }

    else {

        thumbanil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = title.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        title.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 

    }
```

Comment: maybe m.getThumnailUrl() isn't returning null.

Comment: it may return something like " " . Not null and not a valid link. do you get some errors in the logs from Volley?

Comment: I believe that some of the links might be broken, or not converted to valid URI. you can try something from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object ; after checking for null.

Comment: No one is using it now days.