# Volley error java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm getting an error when requesting a jsonObject.

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
       (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        ...
    }
```

I know the issue is in the url string because I need a calculated key to get the object. The problem is that I don't know how to do the right encode of the key to avoid the error.

Here is the way I try to encode:

```
public static String calculateRFC2104HMAC(String data, String key)
            throws SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        return Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()),Base64.DEFAULT).toString();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Anix PasBesoin, I found that the way I should enconded was:

```
url =  Uri.encode(url,"=");
url = url.ReplaceAll("\\%0A","");
```